# @Query con JPA - JPQL marca error

Tags: spring, sql, jpa

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT php.producto.idProducto AS id FROM PartnerHasProducto php WHERE php.producto.idProducto IN :idsProductos")
ArrayList<Long> haveProveedor(@Param("idsProductos") ArrayList<Long> idsProductos);
```

y al ejecutarlo me marca este error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
ERROR: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet => could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Seguí este ejemplo [ejemplo](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#collection-paameter), y nose que es lo que este mal

**Actualización y Solución**:

*El error es por que la variable 'idsProductos', llega en null*

Comment: Eso no es una *nativeQuery* (SQL), es JPQL

Comment: Cierto! ya corregí

Answer (score 1):

Esa query no es native query.

Deberías cambiar

```
@Query(value = "SELECT php.producto.idProducto AS id FROM PartnerHasProducto php WHERE php.producto.idProducto IN :idsProductos")
```

por

```
@Query(value = "SELECT NT.idProducto AS id FROM NOMBRE_TABLA NT WHERE N.idProducto IN :idsProductos")
```

Comment: Es lo que ya tengo, no veo la diferencia